# How HTML content return as an attachment response to download pdf and docx

Tags: php, symfony, phpword

In my Symfony project I want to download html template as pdf and docx.

docx use - PhpOffice\PhpWord\PhpWord;

pdf use - PDFBuilder;

step

1. Save the HTML in table with template Id.
2. Get the html content with template id.
3. Same html template should be able to export as a docx and pdf.
4. Return the document content to the controller as an attachment response.

1&2 steps to understand the process, my question related to 3&4

I have

- Parent Class - DocumentExporter
- Child Class are - DocxExporter & PDFExporter

In child class has 3 functions

- DocxExporter -> getDocxBuilder, getDocx, exportDocument
- PDFExporter -> getPdfBuilder, getPDF, exportDocument

  in the DocxExporter;

  ```
  const DEFAULT_HEADER = 'application/octet-stream';

  protected function getDocx($content, array $sectionStyle) {

    $section = $this->getDocxBuilder()->addSection($sectionStyle);
    $content = preg_replace("/<table\s(.+?)>(.+?)<\/table>/is",
        "<table style=\"border: 6px #000000 solid;\">$2</table>", $content);
    $content = str_replace("<p><div style=' page-break-after:always !important;'></div></p>",
        "<pagebreak></pagebreak>", $content);
    $content = str_replace("&nbsp", " ", $content);

    Html::addHtml($section, $content, false, false);

    header('Content-Type: ' . self::DEFAULT_HEADER);
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="' . $this->getExportFileName() . '.docx"');

    $objWriter = IOFactory::createWriter($this->docxBuilder, 'Word2007');
    $objWriter->save('php://output');}
  ```

in the PDFExporter;

```
   const DEFAULT_HEADER = 'application/pdf';

   protected function getPDF($content, $pageParamArray): AttachmentResponse {
    $this->pdfBuilder = $this->getPdfBuilder();
    $this->pdfBuilder->setPageOptions($pageParamArray);
    $pdf = $this->pdfBuilder->createPDFData(null, null, $content);
    $response = new AttachmentResponse(['data' => $pdf]);
    $response->setContentType(self::DEFAULT_HEADER);
    $response->setAttachmentName(parent::getExportFileName() . '.pdf');

    return $response;   }
```

I tried to getDocx function also return an AttachmentResponse as PDFExporterclass does. but unable to identify a proper way to get as same response. for now in endpoint I am getting a attachment response and null for separately for pdf & docx. how can I change the docx function to return an attachment response.

Comment: probably the language barrier, but I don't get what you're trying to achieve yet, so I'm stabbing into the dark. In my opinion, your exporters should NOT return responses, but either a filename or a stream. That being said, a response can always only be one thing. "Attachment" is probably misleading, as the attachment will be *the content of the response*. it's a different thing in emails, where you can have multiple attachments to an email body. in the web, you need to either make multiple requests for multiple files or return a zip-file with stuff inside.

Comment: in docx exporter can I get page content without use the $objWriter->save('php://output'); with $objWriter->save('php://memory'); not returning anything

Comment: can't you just write it to a temporary file or something? anyway ... theoretically, after writing to `php://memory` you should be able to then read from `php://memory`, at least if I understand the php manual correctly. however, `php://memory` cannot be reused, according to example 5 https://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php#refsect1-wrappers.php-examples and I assume ->save will close the stream ... ;o/ I would suggest just using a temporary file or even building your own stream wrapper

Comment: in the $objWriter->save('php://output'); then in the save function it is creating a temporary file. actually I want to return a file but with above code when refresh the browser it is downloading a file. I think I should get that temp file or I should create a temp file. can you help me to create temporary file and return that file.

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.tempnam.php + https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sys-get-temp-dir.php for writing. to create a response as before, you can use the AbstractController's `file` function `return $this->file($tmpFilename, 'filenameTheUserSees.pdf')`, your controllers should extend the abstract controller

Comment: it is worked. created a temp in given directory and read the file get content. worked it is thank you.